# Perform action in parent on child event click

Tags: node.js, angular, angularjs-directive, electron, angular5

So I'm trying to perform some action on the parent component of the child component when a click event is fired in the child component. Currently I have a dynamic loader which is able to load different child components. The problem I have is that the @Output() is being emitted but the parent component doesn't seem to have any knowledge when this event is fired. Is there something I am missing?

> child2.component.ts

```
import {Component, Injector, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello-world',
  template: `
    <div>Hello World {{showNum}}</div>
    <li (click)="childButtonClicked(false)"> </li>
  `,
})
export class HelloWorldComponent {
  showNum = 0;
  @Output() childEvent = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    this.showNum = this.injector.get('showNum');
     console.log("HelloWorldComponent");
  }

  childButtonClicked(agreed: boolean) {
    this.childEvent.emit(agreed);
    console.log("clicked");
  }
}
```

> child1.component.ts

```
import {Component, Injector, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'world-hello',
  template: `
    <div>World Hello {{showNum}}</div>
    <li (click)="childButtonClicked(false)"> </li>
  `,
})
export class WorldHelloComponent {
  showNum = 0;
  @Output() childEvent = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    this.showNum = this.injector.get('showNum');
     console.log("WorldHelloComponent");
  }

  childButtonClicked(agreed: boolean) {
    this.childEvent.emit(agreed);
    console.log("clicked");
  }
}
```

> dynamic.componentloader.ts

```
import {Component, Input, ViewContainerRef,ComponentRef, ViewChild, ReflectiveInjector, ComponentFactoryResolver} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'dynamic-component',// Reference to the components must be here in order to dynamically create them
  template: `
    <div #dynamicComponentContainer></div>
  `,
})
export class DynamicComponent {
  currentComponent:any = null;

  @ViewChild('dynamicComponentContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef }) dynamicComponentContainer: ViewContainerRef;

  // component: Class for the component you want to create
  // inputs: An object with key/value pairs mapped to input name/input value
  @Input() set componentData(data: {component: any, inputs: any }) {
    if (!data) {
      return;
    }

    // Inputs need to be in the following format to be resolved properly
    let inputProviders = Object.keys(data.inputs).map((inputName) => {return {provide: inputName, useValue: data.inputs[inputName]};});
    let resolvedInputs = ReflectiveInjector.resolve(inputProviders);

    // We create an injector out of the data we want to pass down and this components injector
    let injector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders(resolvedInputs, this.dynamicComponentContainer.parentInjector);

    // We create a factory out of the component we want to create
    let factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(data.component);

    // We create the component using the factory and the injector
    let component = factory.create(injector);

    // We insert the component into the dom container
    this.dynamicComponentContainer.insert(component.hostView);

    // We can destroy the old component is we like by calling destroy
    if (this.currentComponent) {
      this.currentComponent.destroy();
    }

    this.currentComponent = component;
  }

  constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {

  }
}
```

> main.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HelloWorldComponent } from '../../views/main/sidebar-views/comps/hello-world.component';
import { WorldHelloComponent } from '../../views/main/sidebar-views/comps/world-hello.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'main-component',
    template:  require('./main.component.html')
})
export class MainComponent {
    private pressed: boolean = false;
    componentData:any = null;

    constructor() { }

    createHelloWorldComponent(){
        this.componentData = {
        component: HelloWorldComponent,
        inputs: {
            showNum: 9
        }
        };
    }

    createWorldHelloComponent(){
        this.componentData = {
        component: WorldHelloComponent,
        inputs: {
            showNum: 2
        }
        };
    }

    test(){
        console.log("some click event");
    }

};
```

> main.component.html

```
<div>
  <h2>Lets dynamically create some components!</h2>
  <button (click)="createHelloWorldComponent()">Create Hello World</button>
  <button (click)="createWorldHelloComponent()">Create World Hello</button>
  <dynamic-component [componentData]="componentData" (childEvent)="test()"></dynamic-component>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any special reason why you are going through all this trouble to just inject components dynamically and not using ngIf?

Comment: @dexter haven't thought of a better way to do it. I'm new to angular. Also I'm trying to create a sidebar which has children elements and changes a section of page. Idk if my description is clear

Comment: Please see the answer below and also take a look at examples on using *ngIf to conditionally inject/create components into DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing a parameter to the EventEmitter, you need to change your event binding on your component selector in your template to this:

```
<dynamic-component [componentData]="componentData" (childEvent)="test($event)"></dynamic-component>
```

Also, don't forget to change function signature in your component to accept the parameter:

```
test(agreed: boolean){
    console.log("some click event");
}
```

More info on [official docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event).